# Пожарный и пожарник

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Я как-то раз услышала, что работники пожарной охраны обижаются, когда их называют пожарниками. Дескать, пожарник - это  пострадавший от пожара, погорелец. А они - пожарные.

Как вы думаете, есть разница в значениях этих слов?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Из Грамоты. ру: 
С конца XIХ – начала ХХ века в разговорно-обиходной речи, в нелитературном просторечии вместо слова **пожарный** («член, служитель пожарной команды») стали употреблять существительное **пожарник**. Сами пожарные-профессионалы такое именование не приняли, считая его для себя оскорбительным, потому что пожарниками обычно называли инвалидов заштатных пожарных команд, а также пожарных-любителей, членов добровольных пожарных дружин (такое значение слова **пожарник** зафиксировано в «Толковом словаре русского языка» под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова; ср. известное спит, как пожарник) (см. Скворцов, 1995).

Сегодня слово **пожарный** употребляется в значении «боец пожарной команды» и считается нейтральным, а слово **пожарник** – разговорным (см. СОШ, РСС–1). В словаре Даля **пожарник** – устраивающий пожарные команды и заправляющий ими. В современных словарях у слова пожарник не зафиксировано значения «тот, кто устраивает пожар». Таким образом, рекомендации «Детской странички» можно считать неправильными.

Дополнение нашего посетителя Евгения Колобова:

«Было бы уместно дополнить статью упоминанием о толковании разницы между этими двумя терминами, которое встречается в книге Владимира Алексеевича Гиляровского "Москва и москвичи".
Позволю себе привести достаточно большой отрывок из главы "Пожарный":

– Пожарники едут! Пожарники едут! – кричит кучка ребятишек.
В первый раз в жизни я услыхал это слово в конце первого года империалистической войны, когда население нашего дома, особенно надворных флигелей, увеличилось беженцами из Польши.
Меня, старого москвича и, главное, старого пожарного, резануло это слово. Москва, любовавшаяся своим знаменитым пожарным обозом – сперва на красавцах лошадях, подобранных по мастям, а потом бесшумными автомобилями, сверкающими медными шлемами, – с гордостью говорила:
– Пожарные!
И вдруг:
– Пожарники!
Что-то мелкое, убогое, обидное.
Передо мной встает какой-нибудь уездный городишко, где на весь город три дырявые пожарные бочки, полтора багра, ржавая машина с фонтанирующим рукавом на колесах, вязнущих по ступицу в невылазной грязи немощеных переулков, а сзади тащится за ним с десяток убогих инвалидов-пожарников.
В Москве с давних пор это слово было ходовым, но имело совсем другое значение: так назывались особого рода нищие, являвшиеся в Москву на зимний сезон вместе со своими господами, владельцами богатых поместий. Помещики приезжали в столицу проживать свои доходы с имений, а их крепостные – добывать деньги, часть которых шла на оброк, в господские карманы.
Делалось это под видом сбора на "погорелые места". Погорельцы, настоящие и фальшивые, приходили и приезжали в Москву семьями. Бабы с ребятишками ездили в санях собирать подаяние деньгами и барахлом, предъявляя удостоверения с гербовой печатью о том, что предъявители сего едут по сбору пожертвований в пользу сгоревшей деревни или села. Некоторые из них покупали особые сани, с обожженными концами оглоблей, уверяя, что они только сани и успели вырвать из огня".

Цитата приведена по изданию: В. А. Гиляровский, Москва и москвичи. Минск: Народная асвета, 1981».

Правильно
**о бойце пожарной команды – пожарный; разговорное – пожарник**.

Comment: Замечательный, очень полный ответ! Я тоже сразу Гиляровского вспомнила, т.к. до его книги разницы между "пожарный" и "пожарник" не видела. Кстати, есть еще жук-пожарник :)